# Basis for the Dutch authorities denying a Turkish minister access to a Turkish consulate

Tags: election, law, turkey, netherlands, freedom-of-speech

A few days ago, the Turkish family minister Fatma Betül Sayan Kaya was [prevented from entering the Turkish consulate in Rotterdam](http://en.apa.az/world-news/europe/democratic-values-trampled-underfoot-turkish-minister.html), where she was going, it seems, as part of the organization of a political rally for Turkish citizens living in the Netherlands regarding an upcoming referendum in Turkey on constitutional reforms. This followed the prevention of the Turkish 
foreign minitary from coming to the Netherlands to promote the same campaign (see also [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16242/7643) question here on the site). The Dutch authorities also prevented a rally/demonstration from taking place near the consulate. If I understand correctly the reasons given were keeping the public peace, or preventing disorder, or something along those lines - correct me if Im wrong.

I don't know Dutch law and political custom, but - was the Dutch government justified in preventing the minister's access to the consulate, assuming all of the travel documents were in order? Can it prevent demonstrations apriori on the grounds it stated? Specifically, has the Netherlands acted in the past to prevent a foreign citizen from engaging in political speech targeted at the citizens of their own state, but occurring in the Netherlands?

Also, to what extent can it be argued that this action was motivated by the upcoming Dutch elections, intended to make the VVD government appear more "tough on Islam" or "tough on immigrants" or both?

I personally oppose the referendum proposal but it seems to me like these actions are giving the AKP and President Erdogan's government an unwarranted public relations boost.

Comment: @Philipp♦: It's not a duplicate, the FM denial was another event. Two ministers were denied things.

Comment: Two different events, but it's the exact same situation. The answers to both questions would be exactly the same. Which means that it's better to just have one question about this situation.

Comment: I know nothing much about the circumstances and little about Dutch politics. But it seems quite reasonable to me for any country to prevent a foreign government from campaigning, or even seeking influence, in its domestic election.

Comment: @WS2: How is that reasonable? It's not a campaign about internal Dutch affairs, but about internal Turkish affairs? Plus, it's problematic that the government can even do something like prevent rallies from taking place when no illegal activity is involved - just because it doesn't like it. (If that's indeed the case here of course.)

Comment: @einpoklum I'm afraid that I know insufficient about what is happening to comment.